# Limit of $x_n = 0.5(x_{n-1} + x_{n-2})$ - help finishing proof...

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

EDIT: Fixed geometric proof off-by-one error.

I am looking for the limit of $x_n = 0.5(x_{n-1} + x_{n-2})$ with $x_2 > x_1$ arbitrary. I can show $\forall n: |x_{n}-x_{n+1}| = \frac{c}{2^{n-1}}$ (where $c = x_2 - x_1$) and thus existence of the limit (cauchy sequence)(see appended). From there I wanted to proceed:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim(x_n) &=& x_1 + \lim( \sum_{k=1}^n (x_{k+1}-x_k)) \\
&=& x_1 + x_2 - x_1+ \lim( \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1} c}{2^{k-1}}) \\
&=& x_2 + \lim(\sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \frac{c}{2^{2k}} -  \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \frac{c}{2^{2k-1}} ) \\
&=& x_2  + c \lim(\sum_{k=1}^{n/2}  \frac{1}{4^k} -  \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4^k}) \\
&=& x_2 + c (\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{1-1/4}-\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-1/4}) \\
&=& x_2 + \frac{c}{8}\frac{1}{1-1/4} \\
&=& x_2  + \frac{1}{6}c.\end{eqnarray*}
I can tell this is wrong by the example in the book (Bartle Sherbert, 3.5), and I can tell it should be $x_1 + \frac{2}{3}c$ on the penultimate line the same way - but I cannot justify why that would be the case...

Any ideas?

Thanks! Best,
Leon

---

Let $c = x_2 - x_1$. Then we prove by induction that $\forall n: |x_{n}-x_{n+1}| = \frac{c}{2^{n-1}}$. Base: firstly $|x_1 - x_2| = x_2 - x_1 = c/2^0 = c/2^{1-1}$, and secondly $|x_2 - x_3| = |x_2 - (1/2)(x_1+x_2)| = (1/2)|x_1-x_2| = c/2$. Inductive step:
\begin{eqnarray*}
|x_n - x_{n+1}| &=& | \frac{1}{2}(x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}) -  \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}(x_{n-1}+x_{n-2})+x_{n-1)} | \\
 &=& |\frac{1}{2}x_{n-2} - \frac{1}{4}x_{n-1}-\frac{1}{4}x_{n-1}  | \\
&=& \frac{1}{4}|x_{n-2}-x_{n-1}| \\
&=& \frac{c}{2^{n-1}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Your geometric series start at $k=1$, not $k=0$, hence their sum is $$\frac14\,\frac1{1-\frac14}.$$

Comment: So it did - fixed, thanks. Doesn't yield correct result quite yet though...

Comment: Now your SECOND sum should start at $k=0$, once you factored $\frac12$...

Comment: I've checked this @Did and that does seem to lead to the correct result (amazing!), but I don't quite get why I have to do it - care to elaborate? Cheers :)

Comment: See answer on this specific point. (As already said by another user, +1 for showing your work.)

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that you never actually needed to split up that series; the geometric series identity extends to negative numbers (actually, any complex number with magnitude less than $1$). So pushing the starting value for $k$ back down to $1$ as in the first line, then adjusting the index again to match up with the power, you simply have: $x_2+ c \sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^j = x_2 + c \frac{1}{1-(-1/2)} = x_2 + \frac{2}{3} c$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \frac1{2^{2k-1}}=  \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2^{2k-2}}=  \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4^{k-1}}=  \sum_{k=0}^{n/2-1} \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4^k}$$

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly what I was missing. Thanks :)